# Detect maximize event in browser Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events, maximize-window

I want to close the tab when we press the maximize button in the browser.
How can we detect the event of maximize button?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It breaks user experience in so many ways... And further more you **can't** catch the event when a user presses on that button in javascript

Comment: There's no built-in event handler for that, but you could monitor the window's `innerWidth` and `innerHeight`. If they abruptly jump up in value, then it's likely that the window was maximised (or the user just went crazy resizing the window).

Comment: I don't think you can close a tab using javascript. However, i think minimize, maximize events can be caught by the `resize` event

Comment: Can i resize an existing window using javascript?

Comment: What my requirement is i am playing a flash file in a browser, on click of a button the window gets resized to a particular size and remains on top always so that i can watch the flash animation as well as work on other things in my pc and again on click of a button the window should resize to its original level.

Comment: Oh deleted my answer because I just realize that `window.outerHeight < screen.height` due to OS taskbar, so yeah you shouldn't use that approach.

Comment: If i can resize the same window where I am playing the flash file, then my problem gets solved.

Comment: Is there any way to do that?

Comment: instead of maximise button can i detect close event on a browser using javascript?

Comment: Look for a resize event, is my best answer.  Also, the window.screen object has size of the whole screen, just the available part, so your arithmetic might have to make some guesses.

To close a window, window.close() works sometimes, there's some rules I can't remember, like it only works if you do if you do it from inside the window, o r inside the window that opened it.

Answer (score -2):

I guess maximize can be caught with a `$(window).resize();`

You can check if the current size of the window is larger than the previous. But I don't think there is a JS event to detect a click on maximize button.